# Will programs developed using Embarcadero Delphi XE3 work with Embarcadero Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe3

We are trying to develop a form that will be added to a project written and created using **Embarcadero Delphi 2010** , We will use **Embarcadero Delphi XE3** as our Development Environemt, will the code that we will write work on **Embarcadero Delphi 2010** ?

If not where can I download **Embarcadero Delphi 2010**, I can't find it on the Embarcadero  official site.

Thanks

Comment: Some licenses will let you install previous versions as well. Log into your user account to see what's there.

Comment: You can write code that will compile on many different Delphi versions. But you need those versions at hand to be sure.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend attempting this unless you have both versions at hand, otherwise it will turn into a fiasco each time you try to compile between these two.

Answer (score 3):

Previous versions can be downloaded here:
http://www.embarcadero.com/xe3-earlier-versions

Answer (score 2):

Depends ....
if you don't use rtti and generics and remove qulified namespaces, restrict the use of foreign components it could work, but i think it's not recommended.

Comment: @TOndrej Things like `uses System.SysUtils` won't though, which I guess is bummi's point

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Those things will work with unit aliases defined in project options.

Comment: @TOndrej It's actually easier to use the `Unit scope names` option in XE2+

Answer (score 2):

If you are properly registered you have an edn account:

Pick Downloads / Registered User Downloads

It is in there. You should be able to go back to Delphi 7. 2010 is at the bottom of the page.

The latest stuff in XE3 is highly recommended. The improvements over the last few years are definitely worth it, and the upgrade will pay for itself in very short time even if you only gradually learn and use the new stuff.